# getThirdMondayInJanuary(): Not working

Tags: javascript, validation, date, datepicker

I need to get third monday in january. I am trying this is javascript

**@guys who commented: I was trying to implement this.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {  
  $('#holidayDate').datepicker();  
  var availableTags = ["New years Day", "Martin Luther King Day", "Groundhog Day", "Valentine's Day", "Washington's Birthday",
"Easter", "Earth Day", "National Arbor Day", "Mother's Day", "Memorial Day", "Flag Day", "Father's Day", "Independence Day",
"Labor Day", "Columbus Day", "Halloween", "Veterans Day", "Thanksgiving Day", "Pearl Harbor Remembrance Day", "Christmas Day"];  
  $("#tags").autocomplete({source:availableTags});  
  $('#holidayDate').change(function() {  
 var dateString = $(this).val().substring(0, 5); 
 var res = ""; 
 switch (dateString) { 
   case '01/01': res = availableTags[0]; break; 
   case getThirdMondayInJanuary(): res = availableTags[1]; break;
   case '02/02': res = availableTags[2]; break; 
   case '02/14': res = availableTags[3]; break; 
   case '04/22': res = availableTags[6]; break; 
   case '06/14': res = availableTags[10]; break; 
   case '07/04': res = availableTags[12]; break;
   case '10/31': res = availableTags[15]; break; 
   case '11/11': res = availableTags[16]; break; 
   case '12/07': res = availableTags[18]; break; 
   case '12/25': res = availableTags[19]; break;
  }        
  $('#tags').val(res);  
  });  
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: Is getThirdMondayInJanuary actually implemented, or were you hoping the computer would do it for you?

Comment: I tried calling `fixMyProgram()`, but it didn't work. Do I need to call `fixMyProgramPlease()` instead?

Comment: I need money `getMe1MillionDollars()` is not working?? ;)

Answer (score 11):

1. Change the colon to a semi-colon.
2. Implement the method.

Answer (score 7):

This question is so bad it isn't even funny. But at least you know how to comment so I am going to take a real shot at helping you.

Use this library: http://code.google.com/p/datejs/

`Date().next().january().third().Monday();`

Comment: This is an actually useful answer, to my shock. +1.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.google.com/search?sitesearch=www.w3schools.com&as_q=getThirdMondayInJanuary

maybe if you changed your code to (not tested):

```
getThirdMondayInJanuary():  // this is working!
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function to get the third Monday in January of any year as a Date:

```
function getThirdMondayInJanuary(year) {
  var jan1 = new Date(year, 0, 1), d = jan1.getDay();
  return new Date(year, 0, (d<2?16:23)-d);
}
```